# RadListView with tkGroupTemplate with inner content scroll horizontal

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-plugin

**Tell us about the problem**

I am trying to horizontally set the content that is grouped with the function of  but is not possible, because all content is horizontal.

**Which platform(s) does your issue occur on?**

Both

**Please tell us how to recreate the issue in as much detail as possible.**

```
<RadListView
    [items]="dataItems"
    #productsListView
    [groupingFunction]="grouping"
>
    <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
        <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" width="100%">
            <MDCardView width="100" height="100">
                <Image stretch="aspectFill" [src]="item.image"></Image>
            </MDCardView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template tkGroupTemplate let-category="category">
        <GridLayout columns="*, auto" ios:height="50">
            <Label
                col="0"
                style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 24"
                [text]="category"
            ></Label>
            <Label
                col="1"
                style="font-size: 12; color: gray;"
                text="Ver más"
            ></Label>
        </GridLayout>
    </ng-template>

    <ListViewGridLayout
        tkListViewLayout
        itemHeight="100"
        scrollDirection="Horizontal"
    ></ListViewGridLayout>
</RadListView>
```

Comment: Use a ScrollView in group template.

Comment: @Manoj any example please_?

Answer (score 0):

Try ScrollView within `tkGroupTemplate`

```
<ng-template tkGroupTemplate let-category="category">
    <GridLayout>
        <ScrollView orientation="horizontal" scrollBarIndicatorVisible="false">
            <Label class="m-5 h2" [text]="category"></Label>
        </ScrollView>
    </GridLayout>
</ng-template>
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=0Su9bz)

Comment: Modified the preview to show an example similar to mine, with your ScrollView changes but the behavior remained the same, I can't do the horizontal scroll